# How to draw SVG and animation with Animejs

Tags: vue.js, svg, animejs

[image]

Help me please. I had stuck for 3 days with it.

Comment: Have you considered ask first to Google Search, try it out and then, if still stuck, come here with a speciffic question about a speciffic problem and bring your code too?